# Can we get the recently used tags back in the sidebar

Tags: feature-request

I see that the recently used tags in the sidebar was replaced with 'hot network questions'.

Is there anyway we can get that change reversed? I feel there was a lot of value in the old section and only limited usefulness in the new content. The limited usefulness mostly stems from the fact that the same links are already available in the 'stack exchange' drop down at the top of the page.

Is there another way to get at the removed content? Even if others disagree with its usefulness, I loved it and would like to continue using it.

Answer (score 2):

The drop down is changing shortly to a [new format with a new top bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198613/feedback-request-new-top-bar-and-multicollider-redesign) which will be rolled out across all Stack Exchange sites after it has been tested.

If you want to have a look at the new bar now you can do so over at [meta.stackoverflow.com](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) - as you can see, the list of questions that have been moved to the side bar is no longer present in the drop down, which is most likely why it has been moved.

Comment: interesting. Do you know if the 'missing' content is the same as the 'related tags' panel that appears  on this page? http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=active The numbers do not match what I recall, but the tags are close enough I think.

Comment: Well those are "related tags" - it's a list of tags that appear on questions tagged with another tag that exists in the new questions list as far as I know.